# Can you use yum/dnf to install or remove RPMs using %posttrans in a spec file?

Tags: rpm, yum, rpm-spec, dnf

Reading the docs on %posttrans here:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/

It's not very clear what %posttrans actually does. When this is executed is the RPM lock still held by another process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you could that would be bad practice. If you don't need other packages anymore when your package is installed, consider using `Obsoletes` or `Conflicts` to let the package manager do the installation/uninstallation of packages.

Comment: Using Obsoletes or Conflicts in this particular scenario isn't an option, which is why I just wanted to know if it was possible or not

Comment: Rpm is not re-entrant. So while it may be technically possible (I did not even tried) and it may work few times in row. You may suddenly end up with broken rpmdb.